# Integration of GWT 2.5 to GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I am using `GWT 2.4` with `Hibernate 3.0`. I wanted to know what changes I need to make in my application for integrating `GWT 2.5` in my application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing special.

Replace 2.4.0 dependencies with 2.5.0-rc1 ones (depending on how you manage dependencies, either [download the SDK](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/) and drop the new JARs to replace the previous ones, or bump the version number in your POM –if using Maven– or similar build file).

If you're using Maven and the gwt-maven-plugin, make sure you [re-define the plugin dependencies](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html) too (note gwt-maven-plugin 2.4.0 also needs `gwt-servlet` to be overridden); or you can [test the gwt-maven-plugin 2.5.0-rc1](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/c0EQromeRgc/discussion).

Check the [list of breaking changes](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/release-notes#Release_Notes_Current) though; chances are small that they affect you, but there's still a risk.